# Web3.js 1.0.0 contract.getPastEvents return a BigNuber error

Tags: node.js

When I used web3.js 1.0.0-beta36 to sync my ERC-20 token's events, an error occurred,{ Error: invalid BigNumber string value (arg="value", value="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000")

My code:

```
   evts = await contract.getPastEvents("allEvents", {
                    fromBlock: fromBlock,
                    toBlock: 'latest'
                }, (error, events) => {
                    if (error) Log.error(error);
                });
```

Could anybody can help me to solve this?

Bug picture:

[image]